# Perfect array count

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array that consist of n integers A[1], A[2], ..., A[n] (0 ≤ A[i] ≤ 1).

We can make one operation:

Choose some integer i (1 ≤ i ≤ n - k + 1) and then subtract 1 from values: A[i], A[i + 1], ..., A[i + k - 1].

Array is called a perfect if it is possible to make some operations, that we can get array that contain only zeros.

We need to find how many Perfect arrays A with length n exist?

Example : Say we have n=5 and k=2 then here answer will be 8

Comment: Can you please explain how you arrived at the value of `8` for `n=5` and `k`=2`?

Comment: Are you sure the input is both n and k? what happens when you subtract 1 from 0?

Comment: @AkshatSinghal These arrays are good in case N = 5, K = 2: (0 0 0 0 0),
(1 1 0 0 0),
(0 1 1 0 0),
(0 0 1 1 0),
(0 0 0 1 1),
(1 1 0 1 1),
(1 1 1 1 0),
(0 1 1 1 1)

Comment: @EyalSchneider see the above comment

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem yourself? Can you include your attempt? If you haven't managed to come particularly close to a solution, can you at least share a few ideas you've had about it so we know you didn't just paste it here for us to do for you without you trying at all.

Comment: @EyalSchneider (11110) can be converted to (00000) by choosing `i=1` and `i=3`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no effort on the asker's behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a PnC problem. Answer would be

`Σ i = (0 to p) [(n-i*k+i)!/(i!X(n-i*k)!)]`

incase the above is not very clear.

```
p    
____
\       (n- i*k + i)!
 \     _______________
 /      i! X (n - k*i)!
/__    
i = 0
```

where  `p=floor(n/k)`

Comment: @Anonymous `The elements in the array are all either 0 or 1` so?

Comment: How you come to this formula? and did u checked for example?I think its giving wrong answer